# SQLDataSource returns "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" while retriving Date datatype from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, gridview

I have a table with attribute, date, datatype. I use `SqlDataSource` to get the data from database and fill the `GridView` with it displays in " mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format.

But in database it is stored in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.
What should be changed ?

Comment: You want to change the display or the way you stored the data ?

Comment: if you store date from sql to c# datetime type variable it will be changed to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: In Database if the type of the colum is `DateTime` then the data is stored irrespective of the format. You should format it according to your requirement while displaying it

Comment: table has `Date` datatype and I want to change the display in `GridView`.

Comment: Thank you all. Answers worked!!

Comment: whose answer worked. Kindly mark it as accepted.

Comment: StackOverflow was not expecting so fast answers, it asked me to wait for marking them as accepted. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="DBDate" 
     DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your [`Boundfield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx) [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)'s default value is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. Change it to `MM/dd/yy`

```
<asp:BoundField  DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `HtmlEncode="False"` as follows

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="DBDate"   HtmlEncode="False"
 DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}">
```