# SQLDataSource returns “dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss” while retrieving Date datatype from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

I'm having trouble with a table with attribute, date, datatype. I am using `SqlDataSource` to get the data from database which fills the `GridView` with it displays in " dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format.

But it is stored as "dd/mm/yyyy" in the database.

I have tried

My code is as follows:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" Height="456px" Width="1157px" BorderStyle="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}"/>
                       </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
                </asp:GridView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ListSpace]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Sql datetime != c#'s Datetime

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I want the date to show as "dd/mm/yyyy" in the gridview and not " dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Comment: Did you try setting your DataFormatString to the standard shortdate format string? I.e. `DataFormatString="{0:d}"` (as per the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings in the database in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLDataSource returns "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" while retriving Date datatype from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990491/sqldatasource-returns-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-while-retriving-date-datatype-from-d)

Answer (score 0):

c# doesn't have a date only built in type, and neither the .Net framework nor SQL server stores date values with display format.

You can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028) on how SQL Server stores date values,

And [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) on how the .Net framework stores them.

The problem is here: `DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}"`.
I'm guessing it should be `DataFormatString="{dd/MM/yy}"` instead.